# Как получить имя модуля в Yii2?

Tags: yii2, модули

Как получить имя вызываемого модуля, а не текущего? К примеру есть модель `Item`, модуль `news`, в ней строится url:

```
public function afterFind()
{
    $this->url  = Url::home(true);
    $this->url .= Yii::$app->controller->module->name;
    $this->url .= '/' . $this->slug;
}
```

Если использовать эту модель в другом модуле, в представлении, к примеру в модуле `users`

```
use app\modules\news\models\Item
```

То в `Yii::$app->controller->module->name` я получаю `users` вместо `news`. Можно конечно использовать что-то вроде `get_called_class()`, но почти уверен что в Yii2 это как-то можно по другому сделать, подскажите пожалуйста как.

Answer (score 1):

Добавь правило роутинга для urlManager

```
return [
    'components' => [
        'urlManager' => [
            'rules' => [
                'news/item/<slug>' => 'news/item/default/view',
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

И сможешь нормально создать любой url

```
Url::toRoute(['/news/item/default/index', 'slug' => $this->slug]);
// => /news/item/first-news

Url::toRoute(['/news/item/default/index', 'slug' => $this->slug], true);
// => http://site.com/news/item/first-news
```